# How to find number of subscribers of a feed in feedly

Tags: feedly

I have submitted a site feed to feedly as a publisher. But I don't find how many subscribers I have from anywhere. Is there any way to check the subscriber count?

Comment: Hi, I was about to ask a new question but seems you could help me with that. How did you submit your site to feedly as a publisher? I have been looking around and I cannot find it. The only information I found was this and it doesn't work as expected (my feed is not updated whenever I publish a new post): http://feedly.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/206805-what-is-my-feed-url-

Comment: @NoelDeMartin I had a workaround which is to submit the feed into FeedBurner first. Then use the FeedBurner location. Just like : http://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/pixelstech. I don't know why it's not working with our own feed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to type as follows

```
curl http://cloud.feedly.com/v3/feeds/feed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fblog.shonanshachu.com%2Ffeeds%2Fposts%2Fdefault
```

Then response will be

```
{
  "twitterFollowers":152,
  "language":"ja",
  "subscribers":24,
  "velocity":2.3,
  "title":"湘南社中テクニカルブログ",
  "id":"feed/http://blog.shonanshachu.com/feeds/posts/default",
  "feedId":"feed/http://blog.shonanshachu.com/feeds/posts/default",
  "website":"http://blog.shonanshachu.com/",
  "twitterScreenName":"shonanshachu",
  "visualUrl":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3587940795/a0a97a65c5c61bb5641b0d09b6604358_bigger.png",
  "description":"スマートフォン向けアプリ開発やサーバサイドの開発に関する技術ブログです。 エンジニアdommyのつぶやきは@shonanshachu、ソースコードはGitHubで配信中。"
}
```

Comment: This API no longer works if using curl, but still work if accessed from the browser

Comment: To access this API in command line, I need to use some tool like https://github.com/t9tio/cloudquery

Comment: The curl command still works today (2023-04) if you replace http with https.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found:

- Visit: http://cloud.feedly.com/#latest
- Click "+Add content"
- Enter the URL of your feed and hit "Enter"
- Now the search results contains the number of subscribers

E.g.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the following

`http://cloud.feedly.com/#subscription/feed/{RSS_URL}`